# I can't redirect to another page. i=I get true value of islogged but i cant redirect to another page. what is the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

const SignIn = ()=>  //submit function

{

```
const [name , setName] = React.useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
var [isLogged , setLog] = React.useState(false)


useEffect(()=>setLog(true) ,[])

 const submit = () =>
 {
    localStorage.setItem('name','Faateh');
    localStorage.setItem('password','Pass')
    if(name === localStorage.getItem('name') && password === localStorage.getItem('password'))
    {
        if(isLogged === true){
            <Redirect to = "/admin" />       
        }
    }
}

return(
    <div>
        <form>
            <label>Enter your name: </label>
            <input type="text" name = "username" value ={name} onChange = {e=> {setName(e.target.value)}} />
            <br />
            <label>Enter your password: </label>
            <input type="text" name = "password" value ={password} onChange = {e=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}} />
            <br />
            <button onClick = {submit}>submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default SignIn;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) of react-router-dom instead `Redirect` on submit function:

```
[import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
...
const \[isLogged , setLog\] = React.useState(false)
const history = useHistory();
...
if(isLogged === true){
  history.push("/admin");      
}][1]
```

Comment: You can mark it is correct answer to help other peoples has the same issue